# How do I make IEditableObject.EndEdit atomic?

Tags: .net, transactions, atomic, ieditableobject

If I have an Address class that implements ***IEditableObject***, I might have ***EndEdit*** implementation like this:

```
public void EndEdit()
{
    // BeginEdit would have set _editInProgress and save to *Editing fields
    if (_editInProgress)
    {
        _line1 = _line1Editing;
        _line2 = _line2Editing;
        _city = _cityEditing;
        _state = _stateEditing;
        _postalCode = _postalCodeEditing;
        _editInProgress = false;
    }
}
```

If there is an exception on ***_city***, then ***_line1***, ***_line2***, and possibly ***_city*** should revert.
This problem isn't limited to ***EndEdit*** but probably found in other places as well.

Answer (score 1):

Did you consider using a TransactionScope from System.Transactions?  This will make your code block transactional, and will automatically roll back a change if an exception is thrown.

You can gain more control of Commit and Rollbacks if you use CommittableTransaction, so you may want to consider that.